# Selection of priors for a BYM spatial regression model

Tags: bayesian, spatial, prior, bugs

I am using a BYM model in WinBugs to describe the distribution of a non-infectious disease.
The model at present is a standard enough BYM model without much modification, (a Poisson-gamma hierarchical model with terms for structured and unstructured residuals) as follows:

```
model
{
  for(i in 1:N)
  {
  observed[i] ~ dpois(mu[i])  
  log(mu[i]) <- log(expected[i]) + alpha + u[i] + v[i]

  theta[i] <- exp(alpha + u[i] + v[i])
  u[i] ~ dnorm(0, tau.v)

  }

  v[1:N] ~ car.normal(adj[], weights[], num[], tau.v)

  alpha ~ dflat()
  tau.u ~ dgamma(0.5,0.0005)
  tau.v ~ dgamma(0.5,0.0005)

  mean <- exp(alpha)

}
```

My question is about the selection of priors for `tau.u` and `tau.v`. They are both set at (0.5,0.0005) in all the examples I can find.

How are these values determined?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These priors are probably meant to represent a lack of information about the associated parameters.  As such, their parameters are picked mostly out of thin air - the thinking being, I assume, that if you little or no information, you can't do a whole lot else.  What little logic is used is of the "it has a long tail and a peak at zero" kind. However, they are not really very good priors for this purpose.  For a discussion of priors for variance components, see [Gelman 2006](http://www.stat.rice.edu/~marina/stat522/gelman.pdf).  For more on priors for random effects type terms, see [Kass 2006](http://ba.stat.cmu.edu/journal/2006/vol01/issue03/kass2.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Usually your.prior are based on some information you have on the phenomena. However, if.you do not.know is best to.use skeptical.priors (basically almost flat densities)